# Dynamically switch component based on some predefined array by using ngFor

Tags: angular

I want to assign component to each tab separately based on some predefined array data. I'm trying to do that by using ngFor iteration in html template.
But currently it doesn't work for me to specify component to div through iterator. Is there any ways to resolve this problem?

The following is what I'm trying to do.

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ranet6?file=app/tabs-overview-example.html

Comment: Inside mat-tab you need to render the test1 and test2 component. you can do with ngFor index or with custom directive referencing **viewContainerRef** we can achieve it [link](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this by custom directive to element referencing **viewContainerRef**

html

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of menulist[0].menus" [label]="item.label">
        <ng-container add-comp [comp]="item.component"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Directive

```
import { Directive, Type, ViewContainerRef, Input, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[add-comp]',
})
export class AddDirective {

  @Input('comp') comp : Type<any>
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
  public componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver) {

   }

   ngAfterViewInit(){
     let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.comp);
     this.viewContainerRef.clear();
     this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
   }
}
```

Please refer the stack blitz link that changes made in component and main.ts file
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ranet6-m9pp7j?file=app%2FaddComp.directive.ts

Comment: Thanks! That is what I wanted to do. My code merged your code is also working as I expect.

Comment: Works fine, but use ngOnInit() instead of ngAfterViewInit(), or it will cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError